# How to use process sample in order to find high cpu usage in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, google

I'm trying to figure out what the devil is wrong with Chrome getting 100% cpu once in a while. I sampled the process Google Renderer. Not sure where to go from here. any advice?

process sample: https://gist.github.com/hadifarnoud/2371a33a5c3f39ede034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view Chrome's page memory usage by pressing the button in the top right of the Window. There you will get this menu:
[image: Menu]

When you click 'View Background Pages' you'll see a window like this:
[image: Window]

This obviously narrows down page and extension usage by memory and CPU. This should help finding out exactly what's going on with it.

The 'Stats for nerds' link sends you to `chrome://memory-redirect/` which breaks down their memory usage even more.

Side note when I notice chrome using a lot of memory and open `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app` I typically see it is caused by `PepperFlashPlayer (Chrome Plug-In Host)` which is Chrome's built in Flash player. It is [known for hogging CPU](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3UhcL0eaXeM)